# Android: Search widget clearFocus() not working

Tags: android, android-search

I have a search widget on my actionbar but my problem is that when I get back from the result activity the widget is still open. I want it to return on the initial state before I clicked on the actionbar button. I tried on the onSaveInstanceState of the main activity the below code but I doesn't worked. Any ideas?

```
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState){
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    searchView.setQuery("", false);
    searchView.clearFocus();
    searchView.setIconified(true);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below.

```
onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) 
{
     MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.yoursearchitem);
}
```

Call below when you want to close the search item.

```
searchItem.collapseActionView();
```

Answer (score 3):

Try with this:

```
        searchView.setIconifiedByDefault(true);
        searchView.setFocusable(false);
```